# How do I determine the number of Node Types, Number of nodes and VM size in Service Fabric cluster for a relatively simple but high throughput API?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi, service-fabric-stateless, capacity-planning

I have an Asp.Net core 2.0 Wen API that has a relatively simple logic (simple select on a SQL Azure DB, return about 1000-2000 records. No joins, aggregates, functions etc.). I have only 1 GET API. which is called from an angular SPA. Both are deployed in service fabric as as stateless services, hosted in Kestrel as self hosting exes.

considering the number of users and how often they refresh, I've determined there will be around **15000** requests per minute. in other words 250 req/sec.

I'm trying to understand the different settings when creating my Service Fabric cluster.

I want to know:

1. How many Node Types? (I've determined as Front-End, and Back-End)
2. How many nodes per node type?
3. What is the VM size I need to select?

I have ready the azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity) on cluster capacity planning. while I understand the concepts, I don't have a frame of reference to determine the actual values i need to provide to the above questions.

Comment: Did you perform a load test? Where are the bottlenecks? Does your app scale linearly? Shouldn't your SQL Server participate in this question?

Comment: @LoekD No load test performed yet. I'm trying to understand the size of the environment that I should start off with for the load test. While trial and error is possible, the organization I'm working for has a degree of bureaucracy that makes it very time consuming to make changes to their azure resources. I've updated with more info about SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most places where you read about the planning of a cluster they will suggest that this subject is part science and part art, because there is no easy answer to this question. It's hard to answer it because it depends a lot on the complexity of your application, without knowing the internals on how it works we can only guess a solution.

Based on your questions the best guidance I can give you is, `Measure first, Measure again, Measure... Plan later`. Your application might be memory intensive, network intensive, CPU, Disk and son on, the only way to find the best configuration is when you understand it.

To understand your application before you make any decision on SF structure, you could simply deploy a simple cluster with multiple node types containing one node of each VM size and measure your application behavior on each of them, and then you would add more nodes and span multiple instances of your service on these nodes and see which configuration is a best fit for each service.

> 1.How many Node Types?

I like to map node types as 1:1 to roles on your application, but is not a law, it will depend how much resource each service will consume, if the service consume enough resource to make a single VM(node) busy (Memory, CPU, Disk, IO), this is a good candidate to have it's own node type, in other cases there are services that are light-weight that would be a waste of resources provisioning an entire VM(node) just for it, an example is scheduled jobs, backups, and so on, In this case you could provision a set of machines that could be shared for these services, one important thing you have to keep in mind when you share a node-type with multiple service is that they will compete for resources(memory, CPU, network, disk) and the performance measures you took for each service in isolation might not be the same anymore, so they would require more resources, the option is test them together.

Another point is the number of replicas, having a single instance of your service is not reliable, so you would have to create replicas of it(the right number I describe on next answer), in this case you end up with a service load split in to multiple nodes, making this node-type under utilized, is where you would consider joining services on same node-type.

> 2.How many nodes per node type?

As stated before, it will depend on your service resource consumption, but a very basic rule is a minimum of 3 per node type.

**Why 3?**

Because 3 is the lowest number where you could have a rolling update and guarantee a quorum of 51% of nodes\service\instances running.

- ***1 Node***: If you have a service running 1 instance in a node-type of 1 node, when you deploy a new version of your service, you would have to bring down this instance before the new comes up, so you would not have any instance to serve the load while upgrading.
- ***2 Nodes***: Similar to 1 node, but in this case you keep only 1 node running, in case of failure, you wouldn't have a failover to handle the load until the new instance come up, it will worse if you are running a stateful service, because you will have only one copy of your data during the upgrade and in case of failure you might loose data.
- ***3 Nodes***: During a update you still have 2 nodes available, when the one being updated get back, the next one is put down and you still have 2 nodes running, in case of failure of one node, the other node can support the load until a new node is deployed.

3 nodes does not mean the your cluster will be highly reliable, it means the chances of failure and data loss will be lower, you might be unlucky a loose 2 nodes at same time. As suggested in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity), in production is better to always keep the number of nodes as 5 or more, and plan to have a quorum of 51% nodes\services available. In this case I would recommend 5, 7 or 9 nodes in cases you really need higher uptime *99.9999...%*

> 3.What is the VM size I need to select?

As said before, only measurements will give this answer.

---

**Observations:**

These recommendations does not take into account the planning for primary node types, it is recommended to have at least 5 nodes on primary Node Types, it is where SF system services are placed, they are responsible to manage the
cluster, so they must be highly reliable, otherwise you risk losing control of your cluster. If you plan to share these nodes with your application services, keep in mind that your services might impact them, so you have to always monitor them to check for any impact it might cause.